# Javascript forEach where value equals value in different array

Tags: javascript, arrays

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    const ores = "../js/json/oreList.json";
    const priceURL = "https://esi.tech.ccp.is/latest/markets/prices/?datasource=tranquility";

    let oreArray = [];
    let priceArray = [];

    let total = 0;

    // Retrieve list of ores
    function getOres() {
        $.getJSON(ores, function(ores) {

            ores.forEach(function(ore) {
                total++;

                if (total === 48) {
                    getPrices();
                }

                oreArray.push(ore);
            });    
        });
    }

    // Retrieve all items & prices via API
    function getPrices() {
        $.getJSON(priceURL, function(prices) {
            prices.forEach(function(data) {
                priceArray.push(data);
                console.log(data);
            });    
        });
    }

    getOres();
});
```

The first function creates an internal array from my .JSON file and the second function creates an internal array from the URL.

In the first array `oreArray`, an object looks like this:

```
{ id: 1234, name: "Title" }
```

In the second array priceArray, an object looks like this:

```
{ type_id: 1234, average_price: 56.34 }
```

My `oreArray` has 48 objects and unfortunately the `priceArray` has about 11,000 objects.  I need to create a new array by comparing the two arrays and building new objects, where the ID's match.  So for example objects in newArray would look like:

```
{ id: 1234, name: "Title", average_price: 56.34 }
```

Basically I'm having trouble figuring out the logic for:

- For each object in oreArray, find the object with the same ID value in priceArray and append the new array with a new object using values from both arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it this way:

```
const ores = "../js/json/oreList.json",
      priceURL = "https://esi.tech.ccp.is/latest/markets/prices/?datasource=tranquility";

let oreArray,
    priceArray,
    joinedArray = [];

function getOres() {
    $.getJSON(ores, function(ores) {
        oreArray = ores;
        getPrices();
    });
}

function getPrices() {
    $.getJSON(priceURL, function(prices) {
         priceArray = prices;
         joinPrices();
    });
}

function joinPrices() {
    oreArray.forEach(function(ore) {
        var matchingPrice = getMatchingPrice(ore);
        if(matchingPrice !== false) {
            joinedArray.push({
                id: ore.id,
                name: ore.name,
                average_price: matchingPrice.average_price
            });
        }
    });
}

function getMatchingPrice(ore) {
    for(var i=0; i<priceArray.length; i++) {
        if(priceArray[i].type_id === ore.id) {
            return priceArray[i];
        }
    }
    return false;
}

getOres();
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that a good way to approach this problem is by changing the data structure of the average prices a little bit.

Instead of having them in an array, where each item has `type_id` and `average_price` field, you might want to consider using an object to store them, where the key is the `type_id` and the value is the `average_price`.

To be more concrete, you can replace:

```
prices.forEach(function(data) {
    priceArray.push(data);
});
```

With:

```
const pricesMap = {};
prices.forEach(price => {
  pricesMap[price.type_id] = price.average_price
});
```

And when looping on the `oreArray`, you can access each product's `average_price` by simply referring to `pricesMap[ore.id]`

You can check out this JSBin: http://jsbin.com/fogayaqexe/edit?js,console

Answer (score 1):

You can use [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to loop over each oreArr item and collect the data you need in the accumulator:

```js
var oreArr=[
    { id: 1234, name: "Title" },
    { id: 2234, name: "2Title" },
]
var priceArr= [
    { type_id: 1234, average_price: 56.34 },
    { type_id: 2234, average_price: 256.34 },
    { type_id: 3234, average_price: 56.34 },
    { type_id: 4234, average_price: 56.34 },
]

var resArr = oreArr.reduce((ac,x) => {
  var priceMatch = priceArr.find( z => z.type_id === x.id )
  if(! priceMatch)
    return ac //bail out if no priceMatch found
  
  var res = Object.assign({}, x, priceMatch)
  ac.push(res)
  return ac
},[])

console.log(resArr)
```

other methods used:

- [arrayFind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) to check intersection
- [Object.assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) to create the merged object to populate the accumulator

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to change your small json as object

eg : '{"1234":{"id": 1234, "name": "Title" }}';

```
var json = '{"1234":{"id": 1234, "name": "Title" }}';
oreArray = JSON.parse(json);
alert(oreArray['1234'].name); // oreArray[priceArraySingle.id].name
```

we can easily match priceArray id with oreArray.